# Выделение выбранных options в vue-select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select

использую [vue2](https://v2.vuejs.org/) и [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select), в самом select отображается количество выбранных options. Вот так это выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так, чтобы выбранные options подсвечивались как либо (картинка, текст или что либо еще)?

```
<v-select
  class="vs-custom--down vs-custom--filter filters__input"
  :options="arDealers"
  :get-option-label="(option) => {return option.name + ' (' + option.address + ')'}"
  :reduce="option => option.id"
  searchable="true"
  clearable="true"
  v-model="oFormFilter.dealer_id"
  multiple
>
  <template v-slot:option="option">
    option.name + ' (' + option.address + ')'}} 
  </template>
  
  <template slot="selected-option" slot-scope="option">
    "Выбрано: " + oFormFilter.dealer_id.length }}
  </template>
  
  <template slot="no-options">{{ $t('base.not_found') }}</template>
</v-select>
```

с vue мало знаком, я больше по react, но в проекте, к которому я присоединился, используется vue2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть документацию этой библиотеки: [здесь](https://vue-select.org/guide/css.html#overriding-default-styles). Просто поменяйте css свойства активных классов на те, что хотите

Comment: А я как-то сконцентрировался на компоненте, совсем не приходило в голову сделать это через css, хех. Сейчас, после отдыха, это кажется таким очевидным